# Sulu: error when trying to use custom data provider

Tags: sulu

I'm following docs from here: https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/cookbook/smart-content-data-provider.html

Trying to make custom data provider for my custom entity type "MatchEvent":

I did it how it's explained here. Since I have services.yaml file I defined those 2 like this:

```
app.match_event_repository:
    class: App\Repository\MatchEventRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine', 'getRepository']
    arguments:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry

app.smart_content.data_provider.matchevent:
    class: App\SmartContent\MatchEventDataProvider
    arguments: ['@app.match_event_repository', '@sulu_core.array_serializer', '@request_stack' ]
    tags: [{name: 'sulu.content.type', alias: 'smart_matchevent_selection'}]
```

So, if I understood well, after that I should have my custom content data provider named "smart_matchevent_selection" and I can use it like this:

```
    <property name="match" type="smart_content">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Match</title>
            <title lang="de">Match</title>
        </meta>

        <params>
            <param name="provider" value="smart_matchevent_selection"/>
        </params>
    </property>
```

But when I try to edit page containing this field I get error:

**Missing parameter token in Sulu\Bundle\PreviewBundle\Controller\PreviewController**

Exception is triggered at `project/vendor/sulu/sulu/src/Sulu/Bundle/PreviewBundle/Controller/PreviewController.php`:

```
public function stopAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $this->preview->stop($this->getRequestParameter($request, 'token', true));

    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully look at the service definition of the `SmartContentDataProvider` in the documentation, you will notice that the tag should be `{name: 'sulu.smart_content.data_provider', alias: 'match_events'}` instead of `{name: 'sulu.content.type', alias: 'smart_matchevent_selection'}` ...

Then you can use it like `<param name="provider" value="match_events"/>`

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. Now I'm getting error that "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ManagerRegistry" was not found. How should I define "arguments" of "app.match_event_repository"? What is "%sulu_example.example.entity%" actually?

Comment: The fqcn of your entity should go there, in your case probably `App\Entity\MatchEvent` ... this is not specific to sulu, this is just how you would instantiate a doctrine's `EntityRepository` for your entity

Comment: But you could also create a specific `MatchEventDataProviderRepository` service, which does not extend from the `EntityRepository` ... Then you only have to pass the `EntityManager` as service argument and get the real repository using `$entityManager->getRepository(MatchEvent::class)` ... That's completely up to you

Comment: Thank you Luca. I think I'm very close. After I set 'App\Entity\MatchEvent' I can see edit page, but I get error now: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'type WHERE entity.id': Error: Class App\Entity\MatchEvent has no association named type". What can that be? I've implemented DataProviderRepositoryInterface for repository class, but didn't change my entity class.

Comment: That error was created at at /var/www/html/vendor/sulu/sulu/src/Sulu/Bundle/PreviewBundle/Preview/Renderer/PreviewRenderer.php line 197

Comment: I assume you are using the `DataProviderRepositoryTrait` in your custom `DataProviderRepository` service, right?

Do you have something like `->enableTypes(['...'])` in your `MatchEventDataProvider` service?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that trait. And yes, I do have that "->enableTypes[]" and not sure what to put there. Tried also commenting that out, but didn't help. What are those "example-type-1" and "example-type-2"?